# UINavigationBar appearance in Swift programmatically don't work

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, background-image

I am using this code for set backgroundImage NavigationBar...The navBar doesn't appear just!

I am using Swift with Xcode 6.1

What is wrong?

```
    let vista: UIViewController = Vista_Principale()
    let categorie: UITableViewController = Vista_Categorie()
    let preferiti: UITableViewController = Vista_Preferiti()
    let info: UIViewController = Vista_Info()
    var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vista)
    var nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: categorie)
    var nav3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: preferiti)


    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(immagine_NavBar, forBarMetrics:.Default)


    let tab_Bar = UITabBarController()
    let viste = [vista,categorie,preferiti,info]
    tab_Bar.viewControllers = viste
    tab_Bar.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "Tab_Bar")
    tab_Bar.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()




    self.window!.rootViewController = tab_Bar

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


    return true

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `viste` as the view controllers of your tab bar controller. These do not have a navigation controller so they won't display a navigation bar.

Instead, you should define `viste` as

```
let viste = [nav, nav2, nav3, info]
```

Clearly, this has nothing to do with the appearance api.

Comment: gives me this error   'UINavigationController?' is not identical to 'AnyObject'

Comment: That is a different problem. Just add a `!` to unwrap. You will find it difficult to write a program in Swift if you do not understand optionals.

Comment: excuse me, but I am new in Swift...I started a week ago!...Now work! Thanks